# I can't cross-compile a simple program that uses libgd because of undefined references though libgd.a is present

Tags: c, cross-compiling, gd, mingw-w64, lib

I'm trying to cross-compile on Linux (i686-w64-mingw32-gcc) a small 32-bit Windows program that requires (libz, libpng and) libgd.
I have them all installed correctly, as far as I can tell, though the linker keeps on complaining it can't locate the libgd functions I'm using.

```
$ i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -lgd -lpng -lz -lm -o demo demo.o smssc.o
demo.o:demo.c:(.text+0x2d): undefined reference to `_imp__gdImageCreateFromPng@4'
demo.o:demo.c:(.text+0x1f7): undefined reference to `_imp__gdImageGetPixel@12'
demo.o:demo.c:(.text+0x316): undefined reference to `_imp__gdImageCreate@8'
demo.o:demo.c:(.text+0x368): undefined reference to `_imp__gdImagePaletteCopy@8'
demo.o:demo.c:(.text+0x3b0): undefined reference to `_imp__gdImageGetPixel@12'
demo.o:demo.c:(.text+0x3ec): undefined reference to `_imp__gdImageSetPixel@16'
demo.o:demo.c:(.text+0x430): undefined reference to `_imp__gdImageDestroy@4'
demo.o:demo.c:(.text+0x465): undefined reference to `_imp__gdImageSetPixel@16'
demo.o:demo.c:(.text+0x4a9): undefined reference to `_imp__gdImageSetPixel@16'
demo.o:demo.c:(.text+0x4e0): undefined reference to `_imp__gdImageColorAllocate@16'
demo.o:demo.c:(.text+0x569): undefined reference to `_imp__gdImageLine@24'
demo.o:demo.c:(.text+0x5e9): undefined reference to `_imp__gdImageLine@24'
demo.o:demo.c:(.text+0x669): undefined reference to `_imp__gdImageLine@24'
demo.o:demo.c:(.text+0x6e3): undefined reference to `_imp__gdImageLine@24'
demo.o:demo.c:(.text+0x70f): undefined reference to `_imp__gdImagePng@8'
demo.o:demo.c:(.text+0x71f): undefined reference to `_imp__gdImageDestroy@4'
```

this is how I had configured libgd

```
./configure --host=i686-w64-mingw32 --prefix=/usr/i686-w64-mingw32 CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/lib"
```

of course *libgd.a*, *libpng.a* and *libz.a* are found into my */usr/i686-w64-mingw32/lib*

also, objdump output seems correct:

```
$ objdump -tT /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/libgd.a
In archive /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/libgd.a:
gd.o:     file format pe-i386
[snip]
```

Comment: Probably related to wrong library order.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc

Comment: @AndrewHenle libgd uses libpng and libz so it should be first I guess. BTW it didn't work even putting that second or third or last.

Comment: The "right" order shown in that other question has your code at the start of the arguments, dependencies after it. You have the opposite.

Comment: @Mat Oh gosh. I wonder why on MinGW on Windows it worked. Putting libraries at the end seems to fix the linking problem. Thanks!